# Authentication error when using SharePoint Migration Tool PowerShell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Server 2012 R2 file share to SharePoint Online migration

I am attempting to automate scheduling some file share synchronization to SharePoint Online using the migration tool, however I get an error that my credentials are incorrect.

The same credentials work using the GUI version of the SPMT so I know they are correct, and these credentials are for the global administrator of 365 so there should absolutely be no permissions issues.

The error that I receive:
`Task 7967a651-6a2a-47ed-afcd-6b1567496e7d did NOT pass the parameter validation, the error message is 'Username or password for target site https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/FileShareSite is not correct' Migration finished, but some tasks failed! You can find the report and log at X:\log.log`

The code I am using:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.SharePoint.MigrationTool.PowerShell    

$SPOUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/FileShareSite"    
$Username = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"    
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "PasSWorD" -AsPlainText -Force    
$SPOCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $Password 

Register-SPMTMigration -SPOCredential $SPOCredential -Force -MigrateWithoutRootFolder -PreserveUserPermissionsForFileShare $true -WorkingFolder "X:\log"

Add-SPMTTask -FileShareSource "\\file-server\shares\ShareOne" -TargetSiteUrl $SPOUrl -TargetList "ShareOne" -TargetListRelativePath "/"

Start-SPMTMigration -NoShow
```

According to the logs, I am seeing 400 response codes, as well as some 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.'

Something so simple so I don't know what the problem could be; OS is supported, credentials are correct, URL is correct, *all* these settings work in the GUI version of the tool.

In the logs I see references to logging into AAD, we do not have AAD on this tenant, I am a little curious to know if that is just semantics or if that is part of the problem. I would have assumed the GUI and the PowerShell module use the same mechanisms behind the scenes. `Error happened in AAD login MSAL.Desktop.4.37.0.0.MsalServiceException: ErrorCode: user_realm_discovery_failed Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest).`

Comment: The password may contain characters PowerShell tries to expand because you enclose in in between double-quotes. Try defining the password using single-quotes so the string will be taken literally.

Comment: I was hopeful you were correct, but I just gave it a shot and got the same error.

In the logs I see references to logging into AAD, we do not have AAD on this tenant, I am a little curious to know if that is just semantics or if that is part of the problem. I would have assumed the GUI and the PowerShell module use the same mechanisms behind the scenes.

`Error happened in AAD login MSAL.Desktop.4.37.0.0.MsalServiceException: ErrorCode: user_realm_discovery_failed
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest). `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, the issue turned out to be PowerShell using an outdated SSL/TLS cipher. I forced TLS1.2 on the PowerShell session using `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` and it is now working as expected.